# Return objects from Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

How would one go about returning an object from powershell into another powershell script?  I am looking to automate some of my deployments using powerhsell so that we can have easier to repeat deployments with a minimum amount of human intervention.

The idea would be to have a "library" of scripts for the various processes that occur during a deployment that take a series of arguments, and then have a main deployment script that just calls each of those subscripts with arguments for the files being used.  For example, for one deployment, I might have to create A login on a Sql Server, add some functions or stored procedures to a database , Deploy SSRS Reports, update the shared data sources for the SSRS to use an AD Service account, etc.

I am able to cram everything into a single script with a bunch of functions, but for easier re-usability, I would like to take each basic task - (Run SQL Scripts, get a credential from Secret Server , run a folder of SQL Scripts, Deploy SSRS Reports , etc. ) and place it in its own script with parameters that can be called from my main script.  This would allow me to have a main script that just calls each task script with parameters.  In order to do this though, for things like updating the AD Credentials, I would need a way to return the PScredential object that the function currently returns from a separate script instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can explicitly return an object by using the `return` keyword:

```
return $myObject
```

Or you can implicitly return the object by explicitly using `Write-Ouptut` or implicitly outputting the object by having it bare on a line:

```
Write-Output $myObject
```

Or

```
$myObject
```

Comment: Using `return` can interrupt function flow (especially when involving the pipeline) and as such isn't viewed as a best practice among the PS community.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Do you have a link to a MS source for that. I understand that it sometimes gets used incorrectly and thus causes problems for people that don't understand what it does, but incorrectly using a command is pretty much against best practice all the time in every language.

Comment: I'm not aware of a Microsoft best-practices list but there is a community one on GitHub that has many MSFT contributors.

Comment: Beware, though, that returning objects normally does not work across process boundaries, i.e. if you run the script in a different PowerShell process (e.g. `powershell.exe -File script.ps1`) the output would not be returned as an object.